# Picklist with different value and name

Tags: picklist

Is it possible to create a custom picklist field with different value and name. Eg
on the page layout Orange,Banana value saved in db 0,1. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not.

You need a second field to achieve this functionality, probably a formula field but you could also have a text / number field which is updated via workflow.

The formula would look something like this:

```
Case (
    Text(MyPicklist__c),
    'Orange', 0
    'Banana', 1,
    0
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution looks promising will implement it and get back to you if i face any problem.

Comment: See [below](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/155899/7195) this is doable as of Spring '17 if you have different API names and Labels on the Picklist Values.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to use VF to do this as you can't do this on the standard page.  You can take a look at the  documentation [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_selectList.htm).

**VF Code**

```
 <apex:selectList value="{!myChoice}">
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!choices}"/>
 </apex:selectList><p/>
```

**Controller Code**

```
public Integer myChoice {get;set;}

public List<SelectOption> getChoices() {
    List<SelectOption> choices = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption(0,'Orange'));
    options.add(new SelectOption(1,'Banana'));
    options.add(new SelectOption(2,'Some Other Fruit'));
    return choices;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is possible in Spring '17 - [Value Labels Are No Longer Tied to API Names](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_forcecom_picklists_ui_and_api_labels.htm).

You can have a different API Name and Label for each picklist value.